# Modifying existing code to sort a list of abbreviations

Tags: acronyms, sorting

I have currently the Latex code written in the .cls file to display a list of abbreviations as follows:

```
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
```

It is used in the following way:

```
\listofnomenclature{ll}{
GHG     &   GreenHouse Gasses \\
CoMP    &   Cooperative Multi-Point \\
ITU     &   International Telecommunication Union \\
}
```

Is it possible to modify the codes in the .cls file so that the output is sorted **alphanumerically** without drastically changing the way it is used?

Comment: Implementing general sorting in TeX is quite a difficult task. Wait till your list is complete and sort it with one of the many available utilities.

Comment: Is it possible to create a database of acronyms just like the .bib file and then use it by calling \cite equivalent ? And later generate out the sorted list of acronyms that are actually used in the document? If so, can you point me to the right package please? Thanks

Comment: I'd go with MakeIndex rather than BibTeX. Did you have a look at the `glossaries` package? It has many bells and whistles, among which treatment of acronyms and lists thereof.

Comment: yup, i'm looking at it now. So far, I understand that the database file is written as a .tex file with entries written with \newglossaryentry command and the desired acronym referenced with \gls command. In the main tex file, the commands \loadglsentries{<database file>} and \printglossaries are called to identify which database is used and to print the list of actually used acronyms... but i'm still figuring out how to align the list nicely

Comment: ok, i've solved it now. Thanks for the input.. this entry can now be closed

Comment: You may write a self-answer that can be useful to others, if you don't mind sharing your code.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the fun of it: here is a solution that uses the LaTeX3 module `l3sort` and the `\pdfstrcmp` primitive.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*\listnomenclature{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xparse,expl3}
% make @ letter and switch to expl3 syntax:
\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
% variables:
\prop_new:N \l__ivan_nomenclature_prop
\seq_new:N  \l__ivan_nomenclature_seq

% function for sorting property lists according to keys:
\cs_new:Npn \ivan_sort_prop:N #1
  {
    \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
    \prop_map_inline:Nn #1
      { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ##1 } }
    \seq_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \int_compare:nTF { \pdftex_strcmp:D { ##1 } { ##2 } = -1 }
          { \sort_return_same: }
          { \sort_return_swapped: }
      }
    \prop_clear:N \l_tmpa_prop
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \prop_get:NnN #1 { ##1 } \l_tmpa_tl
        \prop_put:NnV \l_tmpa_prop { ##1 } \l_tmpa_tl
      }
    \prop_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_prop
  }

% parse the table like input:
\cs_new:Npn \__ivan_add_to_prop:Nw #1#2&#3 \q_stop
  { \prop_put:Nnn #1 { #2 } { #3 } }

% internal list command:
\cs_new:Npn \ivan_list_of_nomenclature:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__ivan_nomenclature_seq { \\ } { #2 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ivan_nomenclature_seq
      { \__ivan_add_to_prop:Nw \l__ivan_nomenclature_prop ##1 \q_stop }
    \ivan_sort_prop:N \l__ivan_nomenclature_prop
% \btypeout{\listnomenclature} % unknown command, commented out
% \addtotoc{\listnomenclature} % unknown command, commented out
  \chapter*{ \listnomenclature }
  \@mkboth
    { \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature }
    { \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature }
  \begin{longtable}[c]{#1}
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \l__ivan_nomenclature_prop
      { ##1 & ##2 \\ }
  \end{longtable}
  \cleardoublepage
}

% document level command:
\NewDocumentCommand \listofnomenclature { m+m }
  { \ivan_list_of_nomenclature:nn { #1 } { #2 } }

% switch expl3 syntax off and make @ other again:
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofnomenclature{ll}{
  GHG  & GreenHouse Gasses \\
  CoMP & Cooperative Multi-Point \\
  ITU  & International Telecommunication Union
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I read your solution with much interest. I'm fascinated by how Latex can be treated like a programming language and have learned a few syntax from your post. Cheers!

Comment: You might be interested in [interface3](http://texdoc.net/pkg/interface3.pdf), the manual for `expl3` (the programming layer of a yet to come LaTeX3).

Comment: i'm a newbie to Latex, but wow LaTeX3, will keep an eye on it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've decided instead to maintain a database of acronyms rather than to hardcode them in each document. This is so that I can reuse them in other documents. Attached are my codes using the glossaries package. I realise it is pretty straightforward but I will share it anyway to assist anyone who finds it useful.

```
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\glossarystyle{long}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{<whatever name you choose>} % rename title
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}                    % remove dot at the end of description
\makeglossaries

\newcommand\setacronymdb[1]{\loadglsentries{#1}}         % the name of the acronym database

\newcommand\listofnomenclature{
\printglossaries
\par
\cleardoublepage
}
```

and this is how it is used. Note that the acronym database name is Abbrev in this case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]
\setacronymdb{Abbrev}

\begin{document}

\listofnomenclature

\section{Introduction}
This is how I refer to the samples of acronym in the database named Abbrev: \acs{CO2}.

\end{document}
```

The acronym database is just a normal .tex file (Abbrev.tex) with entries having format

```
\newacronym{<ref>}{<abbreviated form>}{<description>}
```

for example

```
\newacronym{CO2}{CO$_{2}$}{Carbon diOxide}
\newacronym{GSM}{GSM}{Global System for Mobile Communications}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Ivan, I am interested to use the code you posted here to sort the ABBREVIATIONS in the list. For now I am using Easythesis template from Sharelatex. This template has three important files 1) Thesis.cls, 2) Addministrative.tex and 3) Package.tex. I need some guidance on which file I need to modify or add your code, in order my compilation success? I tried to generate Abbrev.tex file containing list of acronyms. Then, I added the above given preamble in the Administrative.tex file. But I fail to compile. Hope I get some help or feedback. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: [modifying code for sorting ABBREVIATIONS in Thesis.cls](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222231)

Answer (score 0):

Well I found [this](https://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/~sojka/blog/sorting-latex-acronyms-in-emacs/) solution using an emacs macro.

It is not a way to sort the acronym list using Latex but solves the problem.