# Sorting a list of tokens (not necessarily numerals) in expl3/LaTeX3

Tags: sorting, expl3, latex3

I'd like to sort a list of words according to their lexicographical order using `expl3` code. My words are in a `seq` variable that I access in a stack-like manner (this is not relevant, though). I've learnt of the `l3sort` package, but it seems as though its functions worked only for numerical variables, because I've had no trouble with my code to sort a list of integers but I've ran into trouble with non-numerical data (meaning "plain" characters; no fancy macros, expandable stuff, or the likes).

Is there a ready-made way to do this in `expl3/LaTeX3`? On the negative, could somebody possibly provide some hints as to how to do this?

Comment: I am not being allowed to comment, that is why replying with answer. Check the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7095/37090) of almost similar question [How to sort an alphanumeric list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-list)

Comment: Could you explain the 'trouble' you've had with non-integer values? The sort code is meant to be generic, so it would be useful to know what is wrong.

Comment: Have you seen [Modifying existing code to sort a list of abbreviations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86517/5049) or [Sort subsections alphabetically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52967/5049)? Both have answers using `l3sort` to sort non-numerical stuff with the help of `\pdftex_strcmp:D`.

Comment: @{cgnieder,JosephWright}: It works alright with the ``\pdftex_strcmp:D`` function. But on the ``expl3`` doc, you can read that "**D** [...] means: **Do not use**. This special case is used for TEX primitives. Programmers outside the kernel team should not use these functions!" On the ``interface3`` doc there is but the shortest comment made on this function. Is it fine using it? What are the plans for the ``l3sort`` module in the short-term? Is it going to be bundled with the other "regular" ``expl3`` modules and thus not need to be loaded as an extra package?

Comment: @JosephWright: I get the message ``! Missing number, treated as zero`` by using the function ``\int_compare:nNnTF``. It makes sense to me, since what the function is reading is actually an alphabetic character token, but I didn't found an alternative in the form of, let's say, str_compare:nNTF