# modifying code for sorting ABBREVIATIONS in Thesis.cls

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, sorting, thesis

I am using Easy Thesis template from Sharelatex. This template uses **Thesis.cls** which contains code for ABBREVIATIONS. The code is shown below:

```
%VJ START (ABBREVIATIONS)
\newcommand\listabbrename{List Of Abbreviations}    % title "List Of Abbreviations" printed in "LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS" 
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofabbre [2]{
\btypeout{\listabbrename}
%VJ \addtotoc{\listabbrename}
    \chapter*{\listabbrename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listabbrename}{\MakeUppercase\listabbrename}   }
\begin{longtable}[l]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
\cleardoublepage
}
%VJ END (ABBREVIATIONS)
```

I get some idea from a post by Ivan at ([Modifying existing code to sort a list of abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86320/modifying-existing-code-to-sort-a-list-of-abbreviations)) using **glossaries** package to get the abbreviations to sort in order. I feel his way is much easier. So I tried to modified the existing code in **Thesis.cls** incorporating Ivan's code. I tried to generate compilable code for testing purpose and the code is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{../Thesis}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}


%start section in Thesis.cls%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\glossarystyle{long}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations} % rename title
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}                    % remove dot at the end of description
\makeglossaries

%\newcommand\setacronymdb[1]{\loadglsentries{#1}}         % the name of the acronym database

\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{

\btypeout{\acronymname}
%%VJ    \addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\acronymname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\acronymname}{\MakeUppercase\acronymname}   }
\begin{longtable}[l]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par

\printglossaries
\par
\cleardoublepage
}
%end section in Thesis.cls%

%\setacronymdb{Abbrev} 

\begin{document}

%\listofnomenclature
\input{../Frontpages/Abbrev.tex}

\section{Introduction}
This is how I refer to the samples of acronym in the database named Abbrev: \acs{CO2}.

\end{document}
```

The Abbrev.tex file contains:

```
%\clearpage
\addtotoc{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS-test}
\pagestyle{fancy} % The page style headers have been "empty" all this time, 
% now use the "fancy" headers as defined before
\setstretch{1.3} % Set the line spacing to 1.5, 
% this makes the following tables easier to read
%\lhead{\emph{Abbreviations}}  % Set the left side page header to "Abbreviations"

%\listofabbrenamesvj{l l}

\listofnomenclature{l r}
{
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.5em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents,



\newacronym{CO2}{CO$_{2}$}{Carbon diOxide} 
\newacronym{GSM}{GSM}{Global System for Mobile Communications} 


}
```

This time I can compile this code using my "Thesis.cls" but the output format of TOC and title is not as I wanted.

I hope to get some help here.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: unrelated advice from my side: Delete the whole thing and start from scratch. The template is bad.

Comment: Can you extend the code into a compilable test case?

Comment: Dear Johannes_B, I have added the compilable test case for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i already pointed out in the comments, `Thesis.cls` is a very very bad template. Unfortunately, it is not the only one provided by the website.

Just as Ivan mentioned in the other question, you need to use a package that automates sorting and everything related. `glossaries` can do the job wonderfully. `Thesis` declares an environment you have to sort and fill yourself. `glossaries` gives you some useful commands to use in your text as well.
One thing you have to remeber is running the helper script `makeglossaries` as described in the documentation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{Thesis}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\glossarystyle{long}
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations} 
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{hdd}{HDD}{Hard-disk drive}
\newacronym{CO2}{\ch{CO2}}{Carbon diOxide} 
\newacronym{GSM}{GSM}{Global System for Mobile Communications} 
\begin{document}
\printacronyms

\section{Introduction}
This is how I refer to the samples of
acronym in the database named Abbrev:
\acs{CO2}. The \acs{GSM} is not the same as a \acs{hdd}

\end{document}
```

Please note that i used package `chemformula` to typeset chemical structures. It has a very nice and clean interface and is easy to use. 
Another package to print acronyms is package `acro`. It has an interface just as easy to as as that of `chemformula`, which isn't much of a surprise as the author is the same guy. Advantage: You don't need an extra helper program.

The default appearance differs from that of glossaries. You can change the appearance using options or define some helper commands.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}%Thesis is based on book
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{hdd}{short=HDD,long=Hard-disc drive}
\DeclareAcronym{co2}{short=\ch{CO2},long=carbon dioxide}
\DeclareAcronym{tug}{short=TUG,long=\TeX{} User Group}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms

\section{Introduction}
This is how I refer to the samples of
acronym in the database named Abbrev:
\ac{co2}. The \ac{tug} is not the same as a \ac{hdd}

\end{document}
```

To sum it up: When starting up a project, you need to decide for either `glossaries` or `acro` (there are a few more, but really, does are the two yo can safely work with).
 `acro` handles acronyms, `glossaries` can do a whole bunch of other things as well. If you are consistently using the interface commands within your text, you will get a nice, clean and failsafe result.

If however, your document is finished and you decide to add some terms in a list to form a *list of Acronyms* you should use a simple LaTeX environment. Use a list or a table. If you have 20 entries you can sort them by hand; 50 sort them by hand. If there are a lot of entries, consider  using the solution provided in [Modifying existing code to sort a list of abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86517/37907) by cgnieder, who (surprise) is the author of `chemformula` (and other great chemistry related package) and `acro`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I choose {glossaries} as per your example given above. By the way, appreciate if can align the list left-sided. At the moment the list is looks like being in the middle of the page. Regards.

Comment: @Vijay I briefly looked at this but couldn't see an obvious fix. I suggest to ask a new question. There can't be enough questions ;-)